# AMD drivers install

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04.1 on laptop HP g62-b10sv.I tried to install the ati drivers from additional drivers (fglrx) but it crashes at startup screen so i reinstall ubuntu.Any idea of what drivers to install?my graphic card is ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 Graphics (switchable).Thanks

My gpus Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250 and Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470.
this is the results of

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Comment: Did you had a look to the answer of this [similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/124292/32413) which is the reference about ATI drivers

Answer (score 1):

Install the device driver by:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

create a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/local/bin && wget -Nc smxi.org/sgfxi && chmod +x sgfxi && sgfxi
```

with name for example video.sh, and run:

```
chmod +x video.sh
```

go in virtual console (ctrl-alt-F2 for example) and run it:

```
sudo ./video.sh
```

this script downloads the last version of a script form smxi.org which does all the magick - stops X server, downloads the last proprietary driver form AMD (works for Nvidia too), installs it and runs X

Comment: I tried it but the installation stopped.I think that there is something else to do for dual graphic cards